# C# can't use the "Length" function

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am now learning how to use the For Loops in C#, but when I try to compile my program, three errors in the console appear and one of them says that int doesn't have a definition for Lenght (I'm just not showing the errors because they are in portuguese), any idea about why this is happening?

```
using System;

namespace Giraffe
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int luckyNumbers = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};

            for (int i = 0; i < luckyNumbers.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(luckyNumbers[i]);
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: There is a syntax error in this line `int luckyNumbers = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};`. The proper way to declare and initialize an array is `int[] luckyNumbers = new [] { 4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42 };` ([doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/single-dimensional-arrays#array-initialization))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an incorrect array declaration, change it to

```cs
int[] luckyNumbers = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};
```

You current declaration `int luckyNumbers = {4, 8, 15, 16, 23, 42};` is invalid, you can't assign an array instance to `int` variable, therefore [`Length`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.length?view=netcore-3.1) property isn't available